# How add an imported library to "my code" in Pycharm to debug imported libraries and use button "Step into my code"?

Tags: python, pycharm

I want to use button "Step into my code" to debug imported libraries, such as the "Django rest framework". 
I can not use the button "Step into", because it step through support libraries, such as ipython and Pycharm helpers.

Comment: Have you tried to play with the options in `Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Debugger -> Stepping` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried. I tried to add the libraries `*ipython*, *interactiveshell*, *codeop*`, so that Pycharm would not stop in them, but it still stops